# A basic select query returning nothing in page, but gets results in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a very basic query, raceid correlates to an id from another table. 'name' is a varchar column. **Note:** the following query is the output of `echo $sql`:

```
SELECT * FROM runner WHERE raceid=738 AND name="Varsity"
```

My PHP is this this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM runner WHERE raceid=' . $raceid . ' AND name="' . $name . '"';

$stmt = $db->query($sql);

$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $row_count.' rows selected';
```

I have not prepared the statement in the code above for debugging I've simplified the code.

When I run it in my page, I'm getting an echo of ' 0 rows selected'. So query works ok, but isn't matching. I paste the exact same query in  phpMyAdmin and I get the match I'm wanting.

I have checked charsets - both the table and name column are utf8.

If I remove the 'name="Varsity"' from the query, the query generates results from the right table - so the connection is good. There is something awry with searching for this name but everything looks ok.

What other things could I check to debug in a situation like this?

**I have also tried backticking name** and even to be sure, I have changed the 'name' column to something less ambiguous:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM runner WHERE raceid=$raceid AND `racername`='$racerename' ";
```

**Prepared statement also does not work**

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM runner WHERE raceid=:raceid AND racername=:racername");
$stmt->execute(array(':raceid' => $raceid, ':racername' => $racername));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();

echo $row_count; // outputs 0
```

As I stated before, if I remove the name/racername from the query, the query works. It retrieves many results which match the raceid. And within those results is also the racername I'm looking for. ie. db connection absolutely works, its the right db. **Additionally** if I remove the raceid, and just search for the racername, that works as well and retrieves all the results. so what on earth? it's a very simple query matching 2 things.

Comment: Most likely the problem is the double quotes around the name, I think.

Comment: Are you sure `$raceid` and `$name` are populated in your code?  What does `echo($sql)` output?

Comment: Both of these comments are correct.  It could be either one.  You're better off doing this with a prepared statement anyway.  Which would remove the need for the quotes and make it more secure.  That's really your best bet, since It's not working right now anyway.  (why fix doing it the wrong way?)

Comment: I'd bet the `$sql` variable won't have the query you expect ;)

Comment: from documentation page: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php  **PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement.**

Comment: Additionally, if you swapped the quotes, you could do this without exiting/entering a parsed string:  `$sql = "SELECT * FROM runner WHERE raceid = $raceid AND name = '$name'";`

Comment: @alex: "for most databases" - mysql isn't one of the "most". rowcount works.

Comment: @SenorAmor: changing php string building methods has absolutely NO effect on the file query string.

Comment: Are you sure PHP is connecting to the same database/environment that you're running your query in?  Zero records found and table not error for table not found error, seems to me the tables there but data's different implying different environments.

Comment: @MarcB Correct, but it makes it easier to read (imo) and reduces the chance of a stray quote screwing something up.

Comment: @ksealey I wish you and others were right. But the sql statement I pasted above was echo'd from the $sql variable.

Comment: @SenorAmor Thanks, Have tried that now. Flipped the quotes and removed exit/enter parsing. Still the same.

Comment: @Alex the row count works. If I do just the query SELECT searching for the raceid, then the exact same code gets results and a row count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use PDO and as I commented

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

**PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement.**

So probably you can pass this way:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM runner WHERE raceid=' . $raceid . ' AND name="' . $name . '"';
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo count($rows).' rows selected';
```

And here is more secure variant to avoid sql injections:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM runner WHERE raceid = :raceid AND name = :name';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':raceid', $raceid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo count($rows).' rows selected';
```

Comment: "For most databases" - mysql isn't one of those database. it'll return a rowCount().

Answer (score 0):

Without addressing the SQL injection issue,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM runner WHERE raceid=$raceid AND `name`='$name'";
```

should take care of it if it is a quoting issue, which I think it probably is. MySQL will (usually, depending on the mode) interpret the double quotes in your statement to mean that `$name` is an identifier rather than a value, and `name` should be backticked as it is a MySQL keyword.

But addressing the SQL injection issue would be better and is not difficult with a prepared statement:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM runner WHERE raceid = ? AND `name` = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($raceid, $name));
```

Comment: No. `'` and `"` are both string delimiters in mysql. backticks are the identifer quotes. `'foo'` - string, `\`foo\`` - identifier

Comment: @MarcB That depends on the ANSI quotes mode setting, right?

Comment: true. but then if ansi quotes were on, the query would have failed outright and $stmt would be a boolean false, or an exception thrown.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point. Based on the output, a statement must have been returned.